# Is there any way to use C# code to run client program/ run a batch file in IIS?

Tags: iis, c#, batch-file

I have a task which is to run a batch file in IIS.. I had use C# to develop a webpage which need to run a batch file and uses plink to execute the batch file in the command. I had tried in localhost and it works perfectly. But when i deploy to IIS, it fail. 
The coding i use which is

`Process.Start(@"C:\run.bat");`
inside `run.bat` is

> cd\
>   plink root@172.28.8.* -pw *ServerPassword* useradd *USERNAME* -p *UserPassword* -m -g *groupname* -e 2011-6-6 -s /bin/bash  -c *FULL_NAME*
>   plink root@172.28.8.* -pw *ServerPassword* -m *pass*

Is there any other way to do this??
or is there anyway something like this

> i create the batch file using C# code, the batch file will store in IIS, then execute the batch file in IIS only return a successful message to the client.

Which mean everything done in server IIS. Is there anyway to do it??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This probably should be moved to StackOverflow.

Comment: did you check the identity of the application pool in IIS has sufficient rights to execute the script ? By default, the pools are running under NETWORK SERVICE, which have few rights on the host computer

Comment: Do you get an error message when it fails? There could be a lot of reasons for it not working, including the user IIS is running as not having permiissions to the batch file or to plink.

Comment: What exactly happens? To you get an exception? Yes, you can do it, but you need to grant the app pool user the right permissions, which I don't know off-hand so I can't post this as an answer for you.

Comment: @steve : i will try about this tomorrow and see the result, thanks ya.

Comment: @Tridus 
@Samuel : i do not attach try-catch block on it, so there is no error message. I will try it tomorrow and post it here. Thanks foe the remind

Comment: @steve : im using IIS 5.1 , there is no application pool

Comment: from memory, with IIS 5.1 (XP?) the process is aspnet_wp.exe and runs with IUSR_COMPUTERNAME. Either grants the privileges to this user (not recommended because of security risks it can expose) or, span your process with a custom identity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution.

Inside this folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG`, there is a file call `Machine.config`. Open with a notpad. Ctrl+F and search for processModel, then you will find this tag `<processModel autoConfig="true"/>`. Change it to `<processModel  userName="SYSTEM" password="AutoGenerate" />`

As shown **[here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317012)** .Then save it, make sure you backup a copy first, in case of maybe there are some errors occur.

I hope this help as many of them is searching for this problem(run Process.Start() in C#).

Good Luck!!